# Find max nested list count

Tags: java, oop, collections, java-8

I have this class object called Person

```
public class Person {
    ....
    private List<Person> people;
    ....
    public List<Person> getPeople() {
          return people;
    }

    public void setPeople(List<Person> people) {
          this.people = people;
    }
```

[image: nested max count]

Each person have list of all employees inside and that each person has List of people underneath. How to find the max deep? for example, in that image, max deep is 2. second highest is 1. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure there are no cycles in your graph? Meaning that person.people or one of its children does not reference person?

Comment: yep. I am very sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually original answer was 1+ as I have to deduct minus 1 everytime. Here is the correct answer

```
public int maxDepth() {
        int maxChildrenDepth = 0;

        if(people.size()==0)
            return 0;

        for (Person prs: people) {
            maxChildrenDepth = Math.max(maxChildrenDepth, prs.maxDepth());
        }

        return 1 + maxChildrenDepth;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply:

```
public static int maxDepth(Person p) {
    int maxChildrenDepth = 0;
    for (Person c: p.getPeople()) {
        maxChildrenDepth = Math.max(maxChildrenDepth, maxDepth(c));
    }
    return 1 + maxChildrenDepth;
}
```

Comment: it returns 4 instead of 3. I have substract 1 to the value coming out from maxDepth. Can you please tell me correction?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Depth-First Search. It specifically finds the deepest node first.

```
1  procedure DFS(G,v):
2      label v as discovered
3      for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
4          if vertex w is not labeled as discovered then
5              recursively call DFS(G,w)
```

Have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), for further information.

Answer (score 0):

I think that one of the way (this way might be not the most efficient nor the best one) could be creating a while loop with the recursive call of the method checking if `getPeople(`) returns `null`. If it doesn't, then you could increase counter and again recursively call that checking method. This method should break when `getPeople()` returns `null` and should return the value assigned to counter.